# How stars and bars is applied on this problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations, binomial-coefficients

The wheel shown below consists of two circles and five spokes, with a label at each point where a spoke meets a circle. A bug walks along the wheel, starting at point $A$. At every step of the process, the bug walks from one labeled point to an adjacent labeled point. Along the inner circle the bug only walks in a counterclockwise direction, and along the outer circle the bug only walks in a clockwise direction. For example, the bug could travel along the path $AJABCHCHIJA$, which has $10$ steps. Let $n$ be the number of paths with $15$ steps that begin and end at point $A$. Find the remainder when $n$ is divided by $1000$.

[image]

I am interested in the first solution which I will paste here (from https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2018_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_10)

---

We divide this up into casework. The "directions" the bug can go are $\text{Clockwise}$, $\text{Counter-Clockwise}$, and $\text{Switching}$. Let an $I$ signal going clockwise (because it has to be in the inner circle), an $O$ signal going counter-clockwise, and an $S$ switching between inner and outer circles. An example string of length fifteen that gets the bug back to $A$ would be $ISSIIISOOSISSII$. For the bug to end up back at $A$, the difference between the number of $I$'s and $O$'s must be a multiple of $5$.

Case 1 -- There are 15 more $I$'s than $O$'s.
There is clearly $1$ way for this to happen.
Case 2 -- There are $5$ more $I$'s than $O$'s.
We split this case up into several sub-cases based on the number of $S$'s.
Sub-case 1 -- There are $10$ $S$'s and $5$ $I$'s.
Notice that the number of ways to order the $I$'s and $O$'s are independent assortments because the $I$'s must be in the "even" spaces between $S$'s (i.e. before the 1st $S$, between the 2nd and 3rd $S$'s, etc.), while the $O$'s must be in the "odd" spaces.
There are $6$ places to put the $I$'s (after the 0th, 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, and 10th $S$'s), and $4$ places to put the (0) $O$'s. We use stars and bars to get an answer of $\binom{10}{5}\binom{4}{0}$
Sub-case 2 -- There are $8$ $S$'s, $6$ $I$'s, and $1$ $O$.
Similarly and by using stars and bars, we get an amount of $\binom{10}{4}\binom{4}{1}$
All the other sub-cases are similar, with a total of $\binom{10}{5}\binom{4}{0}+\binom{10}{4}\binom{4}{1}+\cdots+\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{4}=\binom{14}{5}=2002$ by Vandermonde's Identity.
Case 3 -- There are $5$ more $O$'s than $I$'s.
This case is similar to the other case.
Here is an example of a sub-case for this case.
Sub-case
There are $10$ $S$'s and $5$ $O$'s.
There are $\binom{9}{4}\binom{5}{0}$ ways to do this.
We can see now that the pattern is going to be $\binom{9}{4}\binom{5}{0}+\binom{9}{3}\binom{5}{1}+\cdots+\binom{9}{0}\binom{5}{4}=\binom{14}{4}=1001$.

So, the total number of ways is $1+2002+1001=3004$ which gives $\boxed{004}$ as the answer.

---

However, I don't see how stars and bars applied here. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Note: this can also be solved using matrix diagonalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: in the case of $10$ S's, $5$ I's, and $0$ O's, the author states

> There are $6$ places to put the $I$'s (after the 0th, 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, and 10th $S$'s), and $4$ places to put the (0) $O$'s. We use stars and bars to get an answer of $\binom{10}{5}\binom{4}{0}$.

In other words: we have $5$ $I$'s (indistinguishable objects) that we want to distribute among $6$ (distinguishable) bins.  So, we apply the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) formula with $n = 5$ and $k = 6$ to find that there are $\binom{5 + 6 - 1}{6-1} = \binom{10}5$ ways to place the $I$'s.  Similarly, there are $\binom 40$ ways to distribute the $0$ O's. So, the total number of ways to distribute the $I$'s and distribute the $O$'s is the product $\binom{10}{5}\binom{4}{0}$.